# I have a Shop menu in my 2D game and I want to use a drag and dropon the map after purchasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I have a Shop menu in my 2D game and i want to use a drag and dropon the map after purchasing

I have the store script, which is this one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int[,] shopItems = new int[5,5];
    public float coins;
    public Text CoinsTXT;


    void Start()
    {
        CoinsTXT.text = "" + coins.ToString();

        //ID's
        shopItems[1, 1] = 1;
        shopItems[1, 2] = 2;
        shopItems[1, 3] = 3;
        shopItems[1, 4] = 4;

        //Price
        shopItems[2, 1] = 10;
        shopItems[2, 2] = 20;
        shopItems[2, 3] = 30;
        shopItems[2, 4] = 40;

        //Quantity
        shopItems[3, 1] = 0;
        shopItems[3, 2] = 0;
        shopItems[3, 3] = 0;
        shopItems[3, 4] = 0;

    }

   
    public void Buy()
    {
        GameObject ButtonRef = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Event").GetComponent<EventSystem>().currentSelectedGameObject;

        if (coins >= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID])
        {
            coins -= shopItems[2, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID];
            shopItems[3, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID]++;
            CoinsTXT.text = "Coins:" + coins.ToString();
            ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().QuantityTxt.text = shopItems[3, ButtonRef.GetComponent<ButtonInfo>().ItemID].ToString();

        }


    }
}
```

I don't know if I should add something to this script to make the items draggable after purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having your items defined as an integer array seems like a bad idea. Instead create a base class item that contains the variables to describe it like price, quantity, name, texture and so on. I'm not sure what you mean by dragging items on the map, but there are many tutorials on drag&drop functionality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGr-7GZJNXg

Comment: I mean like i want to purchase item from the store and drag them on the background after that to replace with other objects that i already destroyed by clicking on them like decoration replacement .

Comment: thank you the video was really helpful David